# Double staccato?

Tags: staccato

I was reading in "Gandalf" by Johan de Meij in the flute part, and found what looks like a note with two staccato markings on it (vertically stacked dots). I have attached a picture for reference.

[image: double staccato?]

Comment: Most likely someone's idea of "super extra staccato"

Answer (score 3):

It's a misprint. There's a notation for Staccatissimo.  This isn't it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what _is_ the notation for staccatissimo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staccato#Staccatissimo has a picture of the notation.

Comment: It looks like the engraver put the note heads on the D line and then corrected them to A but forgot to remove the staccato dots for the Ds.  And it does look very much like it was engraved by hand.  Look at the uneven termination of the crescendo wedge and the unequal length and distribution of the dashes in the dashed (all'ottava?) bracket above the staff.

Comment: @phoog Not to mention, it would be nice if the *ff* were moved down a bit and the beams of the sixteenths were allowed to get out of the staff.

Comment: @AndyBonner more evidence in favor of the hypothesis that the note heads were originally on the D line.  Had they originally been engraved for low As, the stems would have been longer and the beams and therefore also the _ff_ lower, as in the next beat.